# Parameter validation fails for trainingDataConfig parameter in solutionConfig in AWS Personalize

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-personalize

To exclude a column GENRE_L1 from training, I provided the excludedDatasetColumns object in the trainingDataConfig as part of the solution configuration.

> solutionConfig = {
> 'trainingDataConfig': {
> 'excludedDatasetColumns': {
> 'Items': ['GENRE_L1']
> }
> }   }

But I get **ParamValidationError** mentioning trainingDataConfig as unknown parameter in solutionConfig.

I was calling personalize.create_solution for similar-items recipe.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved with the update of boto3 version to 1.26.165.

Comment: Please add a link to the patch notes or similar source.